# Combine resultset generated by While Loop

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

Iam generating a the resultset set using while loop. But it gives me multiple resultset instead of single. But i want to combine into single resultset. Here is my code:-

```
declare @n int ;
set @n=0;
while @n<3 begin
select @n as RS;
set @n=@n+1;
end
```

It gives 4 resultset  Like:-

```
RS
0
RS
1
...
```

And need like this:-

```
RS
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: Is this for mysql or sql server? Why are both tags present?

Comment: you can answer me in any of these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a table variable:

```
declare @n int ;
declare @t table (n int);

set @n=0;
while @n<3 begin
    insert into @t
        select @n;
set @n=@n+1;
end;

select @t;
```

However, there are better methods such as recursive CTEs to do this.

Comment: will u please give me the example of doing this using CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

create a temp table and insert into it in the loop, then select from the temp table to get a single resultset.

Comment: But In that case,It wont give resultset to java dats why avoiding this way